# PostgreSQL ERROR: relation "cab" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

Our database name is `cab` and table name is also `Cab`. 
When I try to insert data into Table `Cab`, it generates an error that:

```
ERROR:  relation "cab" does not exist
```

Query which we generated for insertion:

```
insert into Cab (Cab_id, Cab_no, Cab_type, Driver_id, Vendor_id) 
         values (80, 'WE-93-BM-9769', 'Teal', 47, 64);
```

Comment: Please add some more context to this question.

Comment: You probably used double quotes when creating the table and now you need to use them all the time. Try `"Cab"` instead of `cab`. You should also read the manual on why this is necessary: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS but in general I recommend to **never** use double quotes (`"`) in SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

try "Cab", table could be created case sensitive